# .joined(separator:) in Swift 4/Xcode 9?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, xctest

I am writing UITests and recently updated to Xcode 9.

This line of code throws an error:

```
let deleteString = stringValue.characters.map { _ in XCUIKeyboardKeyDelete }.joined(separator: "")
```

The error on this line is with .joined(separator:) and says:

> Type of expression is ambiguous without more context

It's inside a function meant to clear the text out of a UITextField during a UITest.

This code was working before I upgraded to Xcode 9.
Any way to convert the syntax for Swift 4 / Xcode 9?

Answer (score 7):

XCUIKeyboardKey is now an enum. Try this:

```
let deleteString = stringValue.characters.map { _ in XCUIKeyboardKey.delete.rawValue }.joined(separator: "")
```

Comment: Great! A tip: Every time you get the `Type is ambiguous` error, it means you have several errors crammed in a single line. It helps to break the line into several commands to see what's going on. In your example, if you remove the join part and force deleteString to be a `String` you can see the `Enum can't be casted to String` error :)